# How to connect my windows phone app to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7.1, dynamics-crm-2011, windows-phone-7-emulator

I am trying to connect my WP7.1 application to my organization on Dynamics CRM 2011.

When I enter my login info (Live ID and password), I get an error (see screenshot)

[image: Screenshot of the error page in the emulator]

Comment: That is TOTALLY all the information we need, awesome!

Comment: Neither is the info available online, if you require additional info do inquire. Else, I'm seeking someone who would be familiar with this specific error. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great example of doing this:

http://crmland.blogspot.com/2011/01/building-windows-phone-7-crm-client.html